# Not able to hide "Check Access" and "Open Dashboards" from ribbon workbench

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, crm-ribbon-workbench

We are facing something weird right now in ribbon workbench of Dynamics 365. We are not able to see "Check access" button on Form and "Open Dashboards" button on Home page in ribbon workbench.
Due to this we are not able to hide the aforesaid ribbon buttons for particular entity.

Comment: Any followup questions?

Answer (score 0):

There are some buttons added by the product in command bar and not all of them are customizable using Ribbon workbench or Ribbondiffxml.

“Check access” is a [new feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/user/access-checker) added to product, this is too early to expect more control around this. See if any privilege available in security role to remove it.

“Open Dashboards” can be hidden by following these [steps explained in community forum](https://community.dynamics.com/365/sales/f/dynamics-365-for-sales-forum/378959/unable-to-find-buttons-in-ribbon-workbench-to-remove). But it will hide the dashboard from users totally due to dashboard removed from user sharing access by security role.

> Select Display only to these selected security roles, and then select security roles that have read access to this dashboard.
>
> For security roles that are not selected, the "Open Dashboard" button on the Lead view is not visible.